# clearInterval Function Starter

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have set up Jquery to start function countset() at a specific time. Can someone please suggest how I can stop the function once the timer gets to zero.

```
t = 30;
function countset() {
    var interval = setInterval(count, 1000);
}
function count() {
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = t;
    t -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `interval` before the functions and can then use it when calling `clearInterval` inside your `count` function. Consider the following code :

```js
var interval,  t = 5;
function countset() {
    interval = setInterval(count, 1000);
}
function count() {
    if(t <= 0 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = t;
    t -= 1;
}

countset();
count();
```

```html
<span id='timer'></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `interval` outside your countset function and add `if(t<0) clearInterval(interval);` to your count function:

```
function count() {
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = t;
    t -= 1;
    if(t<0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m0xstth0/1/)** (interval shortened in fiddle for easier viewing)

Comment: The Problem is i want to start the function at a specific time which is why I had the function countset

Comment: _"Can someone please suggest how I can stop the function once the timer gets to zero."_ And I'm not changing your countset function.

Comment: "start function countset at a specific time"

Comment: You need to be more clear. Is your question about how to stop the timer when it reaches zero, or do you have a question about starting a function at a specific time? I see nothing in your code example about starting your code at a specific time.

Comment: @user5380282, if  the answer to your question is not provided in mine or j08691's answer, then your question needs to be reworded completely. There is currently no other way to read this. Do either of the 2 suggestions work as you want? If not, edit your question to more appropriate to a solution you are searching for but can not resolve on your own.

Comment: Your answer is what I wanted @Runthis